# Can a method return a new object?

Tags: javascript, class, instance

Is the following:

```
function AnObject () {}
AnObject.alloc = function () { return new this }

var obj1 = AnObject.alloc();
```

Equivalent to:

```
var object1 = new AnObject();
```

Same as:

```
var obj1 = new AnObject().init();
var obj2 = AnObject.alloc().init();
```

Comment: Your second and first code snippets are equivalent, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, yes.

The third one isn't `a === b` equivalent, they're `typeof a === typeof b` equivalent, but yes.

One key thing to note is that as soon as you stop treating it like Java < 8, you may be asking for trouble, due to the nature of `this` in JavaScript.

```
doSomethingAsync()
  .then(AnObject.alloc)  // boom!
  .then(useInstance);
```

Where `new AnObject()` is always going to work

```
var getObj = AnObject.alloc;
var obj = getObj( );
```

will not.

Nor will:

```
$.ajax( ).success(AnObject.alloc);
```

Because `this` is determined at the time of the call, and not bound at the point the method is defined (or in the last case, even referenced, as it's provided to the callback).

You might consider:

```
AnObject.alloc = function (config) { return new AnObject(config); };
```

Now it's bulletproof.

Alternatively, have a generic `alloc` method, and `bind` it to every constructor.

```
function alloc (config) { return new this(config); }

AnObject.alloc = alloc.bind(AnObject);
AnotherObject.alloc = alloc.bind(AnotherObject);
```

Now it's bulletproof.